# how to set unknown number of dynamic properties

Tags: qt4

i have developed CW which is of type QTablewidget in which i have fixed number of rows and columns to 3X4 and i have defined 12 dynamic properties to add cell caption.

now my question is if i add dynamic property to let user decide about number of rows and columns how will i define dynamic properties to add text depending on user entered rows and columns.

thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't add properties dynamically.

You can make a function:

```
void setData(int row, int column, QVariant data);
```